# How to deploy gin gonic(golang) app with aerospike on Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I was able to deploy a simple hello.go written in golang(without extra libs).

Can anyone help me how to deploy the webapplication I have developed locally using gin-gonic framework and aerospike(aerospike-client-go).

Particularly I am unable to understand whether I should install aerospike on some other vps and provide its url here in code to connect remotely. I am not getting the best way/correct/working way to use appengine.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you getting specific errors? You will need to use the appengine libraries to deploy it there. (this may be a question better suited for https://forum.golangbridge.org/ due to the broad nature)

Comment: Thanks for comment elithrar. As I mentioned, I didnt understand to try. I was able to deploy basic golang app but dont even know deploying gin-gonic/aerospike with app engine. Thanks for the link to the forum. I have to deploy basic app fast so it will good if I am given answer fast. Thank you :)

Comment: FYI, Aerospike can't be deployed on AppEngine - you will have to install it on a VPS, Google Compute Engine, Amazon EC2, etc - see here for the hosted solutions: http://www.aerospike.com/cloud-partners/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thats what I am worrying/doubtful. I thought I missed something. So, I will install aerospike on digital ocean and gin-gonic on appengine. I will comment again if I need further help. Thankyou.

Comment: You can't install appengine on Digital Ocean. appengine is a Google hosted platform+library combination. You could install Aerospike on a Compute Engine (VPS) and have your Gin app on the same VPS, another VPS, or appengine communicate with it. Unless you built your app with appengine from the start there will be some work to make it compatible, so I would suggest just going with the VPS route or using a service like Heroku that doesn't require modifications.

Comment: Yeah, thats a typo and I edited now. I was about to write aerospike.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97648/discussion-between-user1305989-and-elithrar).